# Could not connect to net.tcp: The connection attempt lasted for a time span

Tags: c#, wcf

On remote build machine, I get the following error when I run my unit test.

**Test method MyNameSpace1.MyNameSpace2.Service.Test.MyPath.XYZServiceTest.FindRecord threw exception: 
System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException: Could not connect to net.tcp://localhost/MyABCServices/XYZService.svc. The connection attempt lasted for a time span of 00:00:02.0086605. TCP error code 10061: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:808.  ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:808**

I have very limited access to this build machine. I do not have access to iis on build machine or the services like I do on my local dev machine. The unit tests work on my local dev machine but they run in to error mentioned above on build machine.

What can I do to debug this error? I have read things like check the fire wall etc. But I do not know how to do that? I can not check if the  windows service for this service is up and running on the build machine. I tried to log into the build machine or connect my IIS to this remote machine but I could not.

Comment: Many people would say that if a unit test accesses the network or database, then it's not a unit test.

Comment: It's indeed not a unit test but a system test, but that's what most people are looking for anyway, although people should be doing both. System tests are better than no tests though.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The most common problem for me is the Windows Service Net.Tcp Listener Adapter is not running on the hosting machine.

Also check your IIS Web Application to ensure Enabled Protocols includes net.tcp. For instance mine has "http,net.tcp" and in my bindings I have "http:*:94:,net.tcp:194:*"

I don't know of any good way to remotely check that IIS is configured correctly or the Windows Service is running. Do you not have a server admin that can look at these values for you?

Answer (score 11):

[image: Starting the Net.Tcp Listener Adapter service has fixed the problem.]

Starting the Net.Tcp Listener Adapter service has fixed the problem.

Comment: Fantastic! Saved my life! you are the best!

Comment: You are the best, thanks for sharing this! I thought I was going mad.

Answer (score 2):

Is `127.0.0.1:808` the actual IP:Port reported in the error?  If so then you need to fix the IP (`127.0.0.1` is synonymous with [`localhost`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost), so that would be your local computer).

Otherwise, this looks like a firewall issue.

There are two common sources of a firewall:

- Router
- OS

Router firewalls are usually found on the router which connects the internal network to the internet.  In these cases you (or someone with access) will need to log into the router and forward the port to the IP for the machine.  This is only required if the two computers which are trying to communicate are not on the same internal network.
For example if your computer is connecting through the internet to the server then setting up port forwarding is required.  If both computers are on the same network in the same office then port forwarding is not required (cases where this is not true are common in larger companies, but then there is an IT or network person to deal with the port issues).

Assuming your server is running Windows, you will need someone with Admin(?) access to log in and either open the port or allow your service to accept incoming requests.  Since you indicated that you do not have access to the server I would suggest having the people in charge of the server verify the configuration.

Comment: The WCF service is running on build machine and unit test acts like a client to that service. They both are on the same machine. There is a port thats blocking the request coming from unit test to the service? within the same machine? What kind of questions would I be asking the admin? thanks for the help.

Comment: When I set up the services on IIS on local dev machine.. I did not run into firewall issue at all? I wonder how / where the build machine admin has setup these settings that is possibly impacting this unit test to connect with the service.

Comment: @dotnet-practitioner If the server and the client programs are both running on the same machine then it is probably not a firewall issue.  I cannot offer much more help, Erik Noren's answer is probably a good place to start.  Other options would be to get access to the server and check the relevant settings.  Since you cannot directly access the server the next best option would be to setup a test server which you have direct access to and set things up to run there.

Comment: @dotnet-practitioner One thought, could you set the build server to try to connect to your dev machine's WCF service?  You would probably need to open port 808 in your OS firewall, but if it worked you would have a short term work around until you get the WCF working on the build server.

Answer (score 1):

As I read it, the "unit test" obviously expects a WCF net.tcp endpoint at some localhost address. So, for that to work you could either

- Add the required service on the build server, which might be a shared server, or owned by another team, or some other issue I'm not privy to, or
- Change the unit test, so that it does not expect a real live WCF service, but a mocked or faked one.

I (obviously) recommend the second alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @sandeep and @Erik for pointing me in correct direction. Mine is Windows 10 system. I do not have .NetTcpListender Adapter. I have Net.tcp Port Sharing service and it was disabled. I enabled it and started the service and it worked fine. Now I host two endpoints at same port like below

```
<services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="mybehaviorConfiguration" name="FirstClass">
        <endpoint address="" binding="netTcpBinding" contract="IFirstClass"
           bindingConfiguration="netTcpBindingConfiguration" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:5000/MyService/FirstClass" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>

      <service behaviorConfiguration="mybehaviorConfiguration" name="SecondClass">
        <endpoint address="" binding="netTcpBinding" contract="ISecondClass"
           bindingConfiguration="netTcpBindingConfiguration" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:5000/MyService/SecondClass" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
</services>
```

[image]